# active directory query vs. sql server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, active-directory

I am currently working on a web app that will only be used internally.  Part of the application requires employee information that is currently stored in our Active Directory.  I have a sql server database already set up that I was going to store the info in but I'm not sure if it's needed.  I can query the AD anytime to get the info I need so is it necessary to store it a second time in sql server?  Will there be any significant performance issues if I am running occasional queries against AD vs. sql server?  It's probably simpler to store everything in my sql database but I wanted to get some other input/advice as I have never worked much with active directory.  (Also, this is not a data/network heavy app - less than 25 people will be using it)

Comment: Occasional queries against AD should be fine, provided they are well filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Honest disclosure - I also don't have substantial AD experience.

If you duplicate the information from AD into SQL server, then you face the problem of detecting when it changes and updating the SQL copy. Your SQL copy will, somehow, lag or differ from the authoritative information in AD and your application will become known as inaccurate.  Caching and ensuring cache accuracy is a very hard problem.  Why take it on if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

For light usage, I think an AD domain would handle it fine. If I understand it correctly, the domain controllers are load balanced across several servers.  It does this for authentication, but I'm not sure about queries.

Answer (score 0):

A Directory is an entity built to be simply interogated using LDAP. The main objective of a Directory is to centralize users informations just in order to avoid duplication in multiple databases.

So the answer is SURE use your Directory and interrogate it using LDAP (via ADSI in your case).

You need to duplicate entries in a database if you begin to plan frequent updates on user datas.